# Polyfill for onafterprint eventlistener in Safari

Tags: javascript, printing, event-handling, cross-browser, media-queries

According to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=beforeprint) & [bugzilla](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19937) the event listener [`onbeforeprint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeprint) is not supported in Safari. However MDN offers a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeprint#Polyfill) that essentially watches for changing media queries.

```js
const mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');

mediaQueryList.addListener(mql => {
  if (mql.matches) {
    console.log('webkit equivalent of onbeforeprint');
  }
});
```

This seems to work well. My question is what would the polyfill for [`onafterprint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint) (which is also not supported in Safari) look like?

While the `beforeprint` event and a media query change to `'print'` coincide nicely, `afterprint` doesn't seem to coincide with any corresponding media query change

Comment: Why not `!print` or `display` ?

Comment: As in a CSS media query? It's a good question, I am mostly relying on them to style to DOM, but in a particular case I'm trying to print the content of an iframe in its entirety. As far as I know there's no CSS rule that dynamically will resize the height of an iframe to fit its inner content. So I have to manually resize the host's document body to match the height of the iframe's body and onafterprint revert the height change.